Unable to Reference XCFramework Bundle
I’m currently developing an SDK in XCFramework format, but I’m facing issues displaying images. The sample repository can be found here.
The Example target is the SDK and includes an Assets.xcassets folder. Within Assets.xcassets, there’s an image named neko.png, which I’m trying to display in MyImage.swift.
Here’s the relevant code snippet from MyImage.swift:
public var body: some View {
    HStack {
        Image("neko")
            .resizable()
            .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
        Image("neko", bundle: Bundle(identifier: "com.example.Example"))
            .resizable()
            .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
        Image("neko", bundle: Bundle(for: Dummy.self))
            .resizable()
            .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
    }
}

The ExampleApp target is an iOS app that simulates the integration of the SDK. I’ve linked Example.framework via "Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content." In ContentView.swift, I call MyImage():
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        MyImage()
        Image(systemName: "globe")
            .imageScale(.large)
            .foregroundStyle(.tint)
        Text("Hello, world!")
    }
    .padding()
}

However, when running ExampleApp, I encounter the following error, and the image doesn’t display:
 No image named 'neko' found in asset catalog for /Users/xxxxx/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/xxxxx/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/xxxxx/ExampleApp.app

The image is not displayed
Adding neko.png to ExampleApp’s Assets.xcassets resolves the issue.
The image is displayed
It seems that I’m not passing the bundle correctly when calling Image() in MyImage.swift. Additionally, when I run print(Bundle.allFrameworks) within ExampleApp, Example.framework doesn’t appear to be included.
I also tried adding the .xcframework built using xcodebuild to "Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content" instead of Example.framework, but it didn’t resolve the issue.
If anyone has insights on how to resolve this, I’d greatly appreciate it!

Your framework is a static library, static libraries don't have their own Bundles. Set Build Settings->Linking General->Mach-O Type to Dynamic Library.
